# How to merge partitions without losing data?

Tags: partitioning, merge

Simplest question to my query is to how 'Merge 2 Partitions' ?

I have 123 GB of free space(unallocated) and a 115 GB Partition (NTFS) with a lot of data (90 GB to be precise)
I want the 123 GB to be added to my 115 GB Partition without any data loss.
I dont have any External HDDs or any sort of memory that could hold upto 90 GB.

Thanks in Advance.

UPDATE :

GPARTED WAS WHAT I NEEDED. I WAS JUST NOT ABLE TO RESEARCH PROPERLY MAYBE DUE TO DROWSINESS or dunno WHAT HAD HAPPENED. ALSO I WAS CONFUSED b/w WINDOWS n UBUNTU. FINALLY N I AM BACK to XP.
ANYWAYS THANKS GUYZ n sorry for the noobness

Comment: Boot from the Ubuntu Live CD/DVD/USB and select Try without installing option. Open Gparted and take a screenshot of the partition structure window. Upload the screenshot to http://imgur.com and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/622877/edit) your question and add the link to the screenshot.

Comment: There is no need to boot from LiveCD in this case. It is a Windows partition. Maybe it is needed to install gparted.

Comment: Note that you're not actually merging partitions, if your full question is accurate; you're expanding one partition into unallocated space. A partition is, by definition, allocated space; unallocated space is *not* a partition. The preceding may seem pedantic, but I've seen horribly confused discussions that derive from unclear communication on this point.

Comment: Did you do any searching of existing questions at all?  You should easily have come across gparted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 3):

If unallocated space is beside your NTFS partition, you can extend it using gparted. If not, you better make a screenshot of you gparted window, then some specific directions can be made.

And noone will give 100% guarantee that the data won't be lost. It is recommended to backup your data. But in most cases it works OK. It is your decision.

Based on your information you can do it, but some moving is needed. Boot from Ubuntu LiveCD, start gparted, do not click any partitions, so they do not mount and do:

1. Click swap partition and disable swap.
2. Delete /dev/sda5 partition.
3. Delete /dev/sda3 partition
4. Extend your /dev/sda2 partition left.
5. Press apply button. It will take some time.

We removed your swap partition. It is too small to be relevant (165 MB). It is not needed this small anyway.

Now run

```
sudo gedit /etc/fstab
```

And remove the line with the swap partition and save the file.

Now we are done. If you want to have swap, you can leave some space at the end and create a swap partition. Then you will need to add it to /etc/fstab file with UUID, which you can find in gparted same way as it was made before. Size of swap depends on you ram size, and maybe you don't need it at all. Anyway swap should be not less than 1GB. Smaller makes no sense at all.

Comment: Thanks for ur quick reply, n as you said i m still stuck with gparted.
But i cannot post images it requires 10 reputation. So i'll try to describe my gparted window.

1. /dev/sda1 at the topmost containing ubuntu
2. then comes the unallocated 114 GB